# VBA - Match Data from another Worksheet based on Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, Let's call them `Workbook1` and `Workbook2`

`Workbook1` : looks like this:(I only put data in Column A)

```
Facility Name| Column B| Column C |
   TGG751-M  |         |          |
   TGG760-M  |         |          |
   TLY701-M  |         |          |
```

`Workbook 2`:

```
Technology|  Facility Name |        Remarks        |
 LTE      |   TGG751-M     |  91%-100% utilization |
 LTE      |   TGG760-M     |  91%-100% utilization |
 LTE      |   TLY701-M     |         Red           |
```

I need to match `Facility Name` in both workbooks and if the `Remarks` of the matched `Facility Name` is `91%-100% utilization` add `two columns` in `WorkBook2` and tagged it as `Selected` and `For Checking`.

The Output would be like this..

```
 Technology   | Facility Name |        Remarks        | +1 Column | +1 Column
     LTE      |   TGG751-M    |  91%-100% utilization | Selected  | For Checking
     LTE      |   TGG760-M    |  91%-100% utilization | Selected  | For Checking
     LTE      |   TLY701-M    |         Red           |           |
```

My code:

```
Public Sub Selection()

Set WorkBook1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)
Set WorkBook2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox5.Text).Sheets(1)

        lngLastRow = WorkBook1 .Range("A" & WorkBook1 .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Index = 2 To lngLastRow   

    Dim varFacility As Variant
    Dim facilityRng As Range

    On Error Resume Next

        lngLastRow = WorkBook1 .Range("A" & WorkBook1 .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set facilityRng = WorkBook1 .Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow )

        varFacility = WorkBook1 .Range("A" & rownum).Value
        varPosition = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(varFacility, facilityRng, 0)

    If Err = 0 Then

        WorkBook1 .Range("A" & rownum).Value = WorkBook2 .Range("B" & varPosition).Value

        If WorkBook2 .Range("C" & rownum).Value Like "91%-100% utilization*" Then

           WorkBook2 .Range("D" & rownum).Value = Selected
           WorkBook2 .Range("E" & rownum).Value = For Checking

    End If
   End If

End Sub
```

How can this be done? Once i run my code its not working but i don't have any error.

Comment: Why does this need to be VBA? A formula to the external workbook (even closed) should suffice.

Comment: @Jeeped actually i'm doing a generated report, one of my module need 5 criteria  for selection this is the last one

Comment: A lot of the issues with this code occur because you haven't entered `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Try that and the code will bug out in various places because of incorrect object assignment. If you could fix those and re-post the code, we could help you with the rest.

Comment: @Ambie tried using `Option Explicit` no changes. my code is running but once is done nothing happens just my `msgbox` if the run is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open workbooks and assign workbook-type vars to worksheets like that. It also seemed to me that your logic in locating facility names that existed in both workbooks/worksheets was backwards. This opens both workbooks, assigns worksheet-type vars to the first worksheet in each workbook and loops through the entries in the second workbook using the facility there to confirm existence in workbook 1.

```
Public Sub Selection()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rw As Long, rngFacility As Range, strRemark As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    'TextBox2 and TextBox5 need to be recognized here
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox5.Text)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)

    lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngFacility = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    strRemark = "91%-100% utilization"

    With ws2
        lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lastRow
            If .Range("C" & rw) = strRemark Then
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("B" & rw), rngFacility, 0)) Then
                    .Range("D" & rw).Resize(1, 2) = _
                        Array("Selected", "For Checking")
                End If
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

    'wb1.Close savechanges:=False
    'wb2.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

Given the nature of the user-form text boxes and double workbooks, I did not test this from start to finish but it does compile and represents the process I would use to go about this.

Comment: thanks i'm going to try, i actually have a script which i'm using for reference but some logic in not their, on that script the logic is upload the source file then copy data and create a localworkbook for data then close the source file. what i did here is upload the file and in the uploaded update it base on the criteria

Comment: I made some errors where I used wb1 and wb2 instead ws1 and ws2. See edits above.

Comment: yap, i noticed it :) question' if i only need one column will it be like this? .Range("D" & rw).Resize(1) = Selected

Comment: Well, if you only need one column you wouldn't resize at all but you could say `.Resize(1, 1)`; that's just useless code though. You would have to quote the word; e.g. `"Selected"`.

Comment: haha yah it's just a useless code xD. i just tried it's now working! thanks @Jeeped your a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem using the code i provided.

```
Public Selection()

       Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)
       Set Sheet5 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox5.Text).Sheets(1)

        Dim varFacility As Variant
        Dim facilityRng As Range

            lngLastRow = Sheet5.Range("B" & Sheet5.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set facilityRng = Sheet5.Range("B1:B" & lngLastRow)

        For rownum = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            varFacility = Sheet2.Range("A" & rownum).Value

        On Error Resume Next
            varPosition = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(varFacility, facilityRng, 0)

            If Err = 0 Then

                If Sheet5.Range("C" & varPosition).Value Like "91%-100% utilization*" Then
                    Sheet2.Range("C" & rownum).Value = "Selected"
                    Sheet2.Range("D" & rownum).Value = "For Checking"
                End If
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Next

 End Sub
```